Abstract __construct with variable argument count
I have a quite a few DTOs like so:
class AccountDTO extends AbstractNestedDTO {
    public function __construct(
        FirstNameDTO $firstName,
        LastNameDTO $lastName,
        BirthdayDTO $birthday,
        CompanyDTO $company,
        EmailDTO $email,
        PhoneDTO $phone
    ) {
    }
}

class CompanyDTO extends AbstractNestedDTO {
    public function __construct(
        CompanyNameDTO $companyName,
        CompanyCodeDTO $companyCode,
        CompanyVatCodeDTO $companyVatCode,
    ) {
    }
}

They're all inherited from AbstractNestedDTO and every property like FirstNameDTO, LastNameDTO, BirthdayDTO, etc. are inherited from AbstractDTO.
In AbstractNestedDTO I'm trying to define an "universal" constructor like so:
abstract public function __construct(AbstractDTO ...$dto);

But I'm getting the following Fatal error:
Declaration of Hoo\Modules\Account\DTOs\CompanyDTO::__construct(Hoo\Modules\Account\DTOs\CompanyNameDTO $companyName, Hoo\Modules\Account\DTOs\CompanyCodeDTO $companyCode, Hoo\Modules\Account\DTOs\CompanyVatCodeDTO $companyVatCode) must be compatible with Hoo\DTOs\AbstractNestedDTO::__construct(Hoo\DTOs\AbstractDTO ...$dto)

So here is my question: is it possible to define a "universal" constructor that will fit all of my NestedDTO?

Yes and No. You could use named arguments.


So here is my question: is it possible to define a "universal" constructor that will fit all of my NestedDTO?

As so often, it depends.
What you'd like to do is not possible any longer since PHP 5.4.0.
As all your constructors are empty and do nothing, this is actually pretty straight forward: Keep the constructor undefined in the abstract super class and any pure abstract classes that are being implemented.
So in AbstractNestedDTO define an "universal" constructor like so:
abstract class AbstractNestedDTO
{
}

As the example shows, the abstract super class has no __constructor() magic method. The constructor method is often generally considered an implementation detail and does not belong into (pure) abstract (super) classes.
You can see this in the open world where you find it most often not defined within interfaces. Compare with the Note there:

Although they are supported, including constructors in interfaces is strongly discouraged. Doing so significantly reduces the flexibility of the object implementing the interface.

As the abstract super class may be used to provide an abstract class implementation (abstract class) of the pure abstract class (interface), the same rules on the universal design of the interface apply to the less pure and more concrete but still abstract class interface of the super class.
From the information provided in your question my impression is you don't want any magic implemented on super class level. Therefore leave the magic __construct() method out of the super class.
